# UP or DOWN Voting in Real-Time jQuery Ajax PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, phpmyadmin, real-time

Alright, here's a quick explanation of what I am doing:
I have a website where people can vote UP or DOWN to a "champion." These champions start with 100 health. If you were to UP vote a specific champion, their health would now be 101. DOWN voting it would be 99.

This site is up and running and has been for 5 seasons now (there's over 1200 members that play). So there's a lot of voting going on at once. It all works fine now. BUT, for this next season, I will be implementing jquery/ajax for "real-time" voting (so the page doesn't need to refresh every time you vote).

The struggle I am having right now with this is, first off, I am not great with ajax/js. However, the main issue is when someone clicks a vote, I need a way to grab the LIVE data from the DB and then throw that into the jquery/ajax query and then output the real data, in real-time (or at least I feel this is what should be done).

There is also a second part to this...people are allowed to vote 3x per hour. There is a notification at the top of the page showing them how many votes they have left, "You have 3 actions remaining." This is again, working fine as is, but I imagine would need to be fixed in with the ajax to be real-time as well.

I hope I explained this well enough. If not, please let me know!
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

CODE:

```
$("a.vote-heal").click(function(){
    var votes;
    var champ;
    var health;
    champ = $(this).attr('id');

    votes = $("#votesLeft").text();
    votes--;

    //the main ajax request
    $.getJSON("/load-champ.php?champ="+champ, function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i,data) {
            health = data.health;
            health++;
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/votes.php",
            data: "champ="+champ+"&action=heal",
            success: function(msg) {
                $('#'+champ+' .health-inner').html(health);
                $('#header .vote-remain').html('You have <strong><span id="votesLeft">'+votes+'</span> Actions</strong> remaining');
                $('#'+champ+' .voting').html('<a id='+champ+'" class="button vote-hurt" href="javascript:;">Hurt '+champ+'</a><div class="button vote-heal action-tooltip">Heal '+champ+'</div>');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What have you done so far? None of this is hugely complex.

Comment: 6 questions, 0 accepted? Moving along.

Comment: Wasn't aware I needed to accept? Actually didn't even see an accept % til you just mentioned it lol. Now, @ceejayoz - if you want I can link you the live site via message so you can see what it is and has been done (not sure if I can actually link sites here so).

Comment: Actually you can link to sites - just paste in the URL.

Comment: Actually Season 5 just ended, so there's no voting atm. Only thing I can do now is send you to the testing site, which would need to be in a private message haha. Anyone who wants it, let me know!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of this is just database queries that are returned with JSON. Maybe have two actions on the backend - vote and refresh.

In the vote method, first check to see the voter's current count. If there are votes left, have the champion's score go up or down.

Then, return this array:

1. List item
2. Champions votes
3. Votes left
4. Error (if exists)

In the refresh method (which would poll the backend server every x number of seconds or minutes) return the number of current votes.

A fairly easy implementation of ajax.

Hope this helps!

---

**EDIT: AJAX learning links**

With jQuery, it is super, super easy. Here's how:

- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/
- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php
- Official website: http://www.json.org/
- http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_JSON_(_JavaScript_Object_Notation_)

Comment: Thank you for the response! I have never worked with JSON before (not even sure what its purpose is atm lol). Is there any place you recommend I go to get a quick refresher on it? PS: Thanks for the bolded statement, I went and accepted some answers :)

Comment: Thanks, and I took off the reference to that (I don't want to embarrass you). And I updated the post with a few links.

Comment: Awesome, I will go through those links when I get the chance! Hopefully I can learn it quick and easily, lol.

Comment: Good! Please remember to check as answer and upvote if this answers your question.

Comment: I will. I just want to see if anyone else wants to chime in first :P

Comment: I think I've figured json out a bit. I do have a quick question though...would it work if say, you click UP or DOWN then the data is refreshed grabbing the live data (I am guessing having JSON point to a specific custom page with this function on it and then returning the data to the votes.php). Once that is done now it goes ahead and adds your vote? Is there a way to make the php not run until the jquery/json/ajax is successful?

Comment: You can send up multiple queries. For example in the $.getJSON function, there is a `complete` anonymous function that you can pass in when the initial call was successful. You could then call your refresh stats function. Or wrap the refresh stats function in a timer with some logic to make sure that multiple calls aren't fired. Does that help?

Comment: I believe so. Granted I am beat right now so I will post back to this whenever I can get this working haha. Thanks for all the help so far!

Comment: Right now when you click to vote it pulls in the live stats and then displays the new updated stats fine. However, I am struggling with getting the ajax to post to the server. I know it's not the php since that file was working fine before. I will add my jquery in my answer to help see what's wrong.

Comment: I figured it out, I just had to match up the AJAX TYPE with how I was grabbing the parameters in the php file :) thanks again!